# Apply a function to specific rows of a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a 2 dimensional array, a function, and a "mask" of specific rows, as below:

```
my_array = np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]])
my_mask = np.array([0,1,0,1])
my_func = lambda x: x * 2
```

How can I apply this function to the rows of the the array that are true in the mask? I.e. for the example above, the result would be:

```
array([[0,1],[4,6],[4,5],[12,14]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
mask = my_mask==1
my_array[mask] = my_func(my_array[mask])
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  6],
       [ 4,  5],
       [12, 14]])
```

Comment: Or, `mask = my_mask.astype(bool)`.